# Grails: how to extend FormTagLib?

Tags: grails, taglib

So i am trying to implement an improved version of the available form tags so I am extending `FormTagLib`.  I am tryign to do a simple test with teh `textField` tag but I can't seem to even figure out which method is getting called on the tag.  I have override every available `textField` method available but none of them are getting hit

```
class TestTagLib extends FormTagLib {
static namespace = "test"

@Override
Object textField(Map attrs) {
    return super.textField(attrs)
}

@Override
Object textField() {
    return super.textField()
}

@Override
Object textField(Map attrs, CharSequence body) {
    return super.textField(attrs, body)
}

@Override
Object textField(Closure body) {
    return super.textField(body)
}

@Override
Object textField(Map attrs, Closure body) {
    return super.textField(attrs, body)
}
}
```

I have tried putting breakpoints, console outputs for each method but nothing happens.  The input fields are being generated just fine, but it doesn't seem to be using my code to do it.  Heck i have even tried completely removing the call the super class and everything still works.

```
<test:textField name="test"/>  
<input type="text" name="test" value="" id="test" />
```

What am I missing here and how do I intercept the creation of the textfield so I can make my modifications?

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at how the `FormTagLib` is implemented?

I think most tags are defined as Closures, like `textField = { … }`. This causes the implementation of the `textField` method to be replaced with the code between the `{}`.

I believe your example is a demonstration of the risks of extension. I think delegation is usually a better solution. Not sure if the tagLibs are spring beans, but you could try something like this (not tested):

```
class TestTagLib {
    def formTagLib

    def textField(args) {
        formTagLib.textField(args)
    }
}
```